# ImportError: No module named jedi

Tags: kivy, python-3.4, kivy-language

I work with `Windows 7`, `python 3.4` and `kivy 1.9.1`
After following instructions from `kivy-designer` installation docs and installing all the modules needed correctly, try to run the app from `cmd` with `python -m designer` get the error from the title:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
     exec code in run_globals
   File "C:\Users\milos.grujic\Desktop\kivy-designer\designer\__main__.py", line
 3, in <module>
     from designer.app import DesignerApp
   File "designer\app.py", line 9, in <module>
     from designer.components.designer_content import DesignerContent
   File "designer\components\designer_content.py", line 5, in <module>
     from designer.uix.py_code_input import PyScrollView
   File "designer\uix\py_code_input.py", line 1, in <module>
     import jedi
 ImportError: No module named jedi
```

I have installed the kivy itself and succesfully built test apps with it.
When I try to install the said module through `pip install jedi` the `cmd` reports it is already installed.
I've tried to find questions about this with no yield.
Ther is a note in the installation docs about *"install FileBrowser"* step:

> (on windows use kivy.bat in the kivy folder):

and then the command `garden install filebrowser`.
I am unsure how to implement this or what i should do with the `kivy.bat`.

What am I missing, How do i make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `Python 3.4` but in your logs I see that program run with `Python 2.7`

> File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main

I think that problem in a Windows PATH. Add `Python 3.4` in PATH or run program using 
`path\to\python3 -m designer`

Comment: on windows `py -3 -m designer` should work if the `py` helper is installed.

Comment: Both approaches worked, i the second one saves a bit of time, the first one was the cause of the problem.